# multiple actions with different params structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, postman, rails-api

I have a Test api app using which I'm consuming different actions in a controller. But i'm not able to implement it properly.

this controller doesn't have a model. it just delegates control to some services. i'm not able to send post data to the actions.

```
class SimplexController < ApplicationController
    def initiate_request
        response = SimplexServices.new.initiate_request simplex_params
        render json: response
    end


    def update_kyc
        response = SimplexServices.new.initiate_kyc update_kyc_params
        render json: response
    end

    private 
    def simplex_params
        params.permit!
    end

    def update_kyc_params
        params.permit!
    end
end
```

for **initiate_request** i have a post data in the body like below

```
{
  "account_details": {
    "logins": [
      {
        "id": "200",
        "ip": "192.117.97.229",
        "uaid": "c387c6q6sr27csbuftfvq9v652",
        "timestamp": "2017-06-18T11:20:25Z",
        "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36",
        "is_api_initiated": false,
        "http_accept_language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6"
      }
    ],
    "is_2fa_enabled": false,
    "partner_end_user_id": "246915",
    "identity_kyc_details": {
      "last_name": "Durden",
      "first_name": "Tyler",
      "document_id": "AB7654321"
    },
    "last_kyc_verification_timestamp": "2015-12-31T16:03:47Z"
  },
  "personal_details": {
    "email": "tylerdurden@paperstsoap.com",
    "phone": "+12885550153",
    "gender": "m",
    "address": {
      "zip": "19808",
      "city": "Bradford",
      "country": "US",
      "state": "DE",
      "address_line_1": "537 Paper street"
    },
    "last_name": "Durden",
    "first_name": "Tyler",
    "middle_name": "",
    "date_of_birth_ts": "1972-02-22T12:00:00Z"
  },
  "transaction_details": {
    "last_20_txs": [],
    "current_balance": {
      "amount": 0,
      "currency": "usd"
    },
    "payment_details": {
      "order_id": "PRTNR135791",
      "payment_id": "E98986D8-03C0-D777-07CD-C56496E2F266",
      "fiat_total_amount": {
        "amount": 1433.25,
        "currency": "usd"
      },
      "payment_flow_type": "deposit",
      "destination_wallet": {
        "address": "16M8D1ZgkWjziw8BaJDT4w1uBF4whfG7mW",
        "currency": "btc"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

for **update_kyc** below is the post request

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "document_type_id": "1",
      "document_number": "doc123"
    },
    {
      "document_type_id": "2",
      "document_number": "doc456"
    }
  ]
}
```

how will i permit this in my controller?

right now i allowed everything using the below code. but its bad to allow everything.

```
private 
def simplex_params
  params.permit!
end
```

How i must implement this situation in the controller ??

Thanks,
Ajith

Answer (score 0):

Firstly regarding the usage of permit, it depends on the requirement. If the data related is not sensitive you can skip permit and let all parameters be updated in mass update. Permit is mainly used to safeguard the application from mass assignment when the model contains sensitive data like password, role etc.

When json data is passed to Rails api, permit can be used on the params, just select the key and go down the hash as required. From the docs:

```
   params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
   person: {
   name: "Francesco",
   age:  22,
   role: "admin"
     }
   })

permitted = params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
permitted            # => <ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Francesco", "age"=>22} permitted: true>
```

In your case, parse through the JSON and delete the keys not required

Comment: I need all the params should be consumed in the action. concern is that params structure must allow the above mentioned json structure only.no extra keys and values must be allowed.

Comment: if your json structure needs to be fixed and the source from where json comes can be any third party, then you need to reframe the structure in controller to get total control over data sent